# How to check if an array contains a certain String without looping

Tags: java, arrays, search

I need to check if a specific variable is in a very large array of Strings (1000+), however doing it with just a for loop and comparing each time would be slow. Is there an alternate method to the way I am using below?

```
    String[] easyWords= new String[]{"integer","project","octopus"}; //+1000s more words
            String easyrnd = (easywords[new Random().nextInt(easywords.length)]);
            String letterguess = consolereader.nextLine();
            for(int i=0;i<easyWords.length;i++){
                if(letterguess==easywords[i]){
                  // do something
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `easyrnd.contains(letterguess)` to check if `letterguess` exists in `easyrnd`.